# $f$ is a twice-differentiable function, prove there is some $x\in (-1, 1)$ such that $f '' (x) = 0$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a twice-differentiable function and that $f(-1) = -1,\; f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

Prove that there exists some $x \in (-1, 1)$ such that $f''(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

By MVT, there is some $c \in (-1, 0)$ and some $d \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c) = f'(d) = 1$. Thus, using Rolle's theorem on $f'$, $f''$ vanishes somewhere in $(c,d) \subset (-1,1)$.